# Checking for multiple layers existing using arcpy.Exists

Tags: arcpy

Is it possible to check for more than one layer at a time?

I would like to do this (pseudocode):

```
if arcpy.Exists(vriLyr AND rsltLyr AND  forCovLyr):
     <skip ahead>
else:
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(vriLyr, "INTERSECT", areaBoundary)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(rsltLyr, "INTERSECT", areaBoundary)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(forCovLyr, "INTERSECT", areaBoundary)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only pass one dataset at a time to `arcpy.Exists`, but you just as easily can chain them together with `and`:

```
if arcpy.Exists(vriLyr) and arcpy.Exists(rsltLyr) and arcpy.Exists(forCovLyr):
```

This can get pretty unwieldy once the number of layers starts to grow, so I'd suggest the equivalent:

```
if all(arcpy.Exists(lyr) for lyr in [vriLyr, rsltLyr, forCovLyr]):
```

Comment: Did not know about the all() function, like it!

Comment: [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) are pretty neat.